# az devops login inside docker container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

As per docs from microsoft PAT can be used for `az devops` login as below

```
cat my_pat_token.txt | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/contoso/
```

However, the same thing does not work when inside docker container

Here is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:latest

RUN az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt

COPY my_pat_token.txt .

RUN cat my_pat_token.txt | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/contoso/
```

I get below error message

```
WARNING: Unable to use secure credential store in this environment.
WARNING: Please refer to alternate methods at https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth
```